# Python, Pytorch, having trouble using cuda

Tags: python, pytorch

OS: Windows 10

Python 3.7.4 (Conda)

GPU: GTX 980

So I installed CUDA toolkit v.10.1, got the matching cuDNN files, installed the cuda 10.1 enabled pytorch version and in addition to that i updated my gpu drivers. but if i now try to check wether my gpu is available with `torch.cuda.is_available()` it still get a `False`. Any Ideas??

Comment: Are you passing any environmental variable that force not use the GPU?

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli I don't think so. This is the whole code  ```import torch  
print(torch.cuda.is_available())``` But I'm not sure wether i understood your question right.

Comment: Is python (before actually running the code) invoked with other additional global environmental variables? I hope it is more clear now

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli well I am using Anaconda if that counts as global environment, but i don't recall doing any extra settings in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your python is running on GPU instead of CPU.

You can do this by starting your IDE on GPU by selecting from right-click options. Just right click on your IDE and select `Run with graphics processer`. Like Shown in picture below.

[image: Starting program with graphics processor]

Alternatively, you can go to `Nvidia Control Panel > Manage 3D Settings > Program Settings` and customize the default Graphics Processor of Python and your IDE to NVIDIA GPU. The control panel can be seen below.

[image: Nvidia Control Panel]

Comment: ![Error_msg](https://imgur.com/KojIIsU).  This is the Error that I get when I try to start VS code with my gpu. Also  about the alternative, it doesn't show VS code as a programm for me and I have no idea why. I also tried reinstalling it.

Comment: Re-install Nvidia NSight Graphics from `https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics`. Also try using another IDE than VS Code.

Comment: You can add VS Code in Nvidia Program Settings by using `Add` button and locating the executable file of it from your program files.

Comment: I just did both of those things and it still returns a ```False``` (tried it both in VS Code, and Jupyter Notebook).